# Xamarin Code Behind

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uibutton, event-handling

I have seen and read online, that for example, if you double click on a button in Xamarin IOS that it will automatically produce code behind for that event handler. When I attempt this it doesn't work, any ideas why?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio ? Are you using storyboards ?

Comment: Xamarin studio and im using storyboards

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 0):

I use VisualStudio and not Xamarin Studio, but it should be the same : if you click on your button, and go to the property pane, you should find something called "TouchUpInside". Then you can give a name to this property, and therefore the IDE will produce code behind for that event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I have occasionally seen that as well. (I'm using Visual Studio on the Mac). I can make it happen if the code already exists. For example, Add a new button, Double click it (it should work). Double click again, and you can't add new code, but it takes you to the right place in the code.

Sometimes it may just be a naming thing, where the system thinks the button exists but you don't.  For example, in the Widget, make sure the Name property matches the prefix to the TouchUpInsideEvent Handler (under Properties->Widget->Name, the prefix should match Properties->Events->Touch->Up Inside). You should see a similar method in the associated ViewController class